# How to make elements overlayed without absolute positioning

Tags: css, transform, css-position

I'm making a slider using css3 transitions. Each slide has a different height (it could contain text/images/videos/mix all of it), width is the same but responsive (100% of the parent).

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide_container">
        <div class="slide current">Different amount of content</div>
        <div class="slide">Different amount of content</div>
        <div class="slide">Different amount of content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment I make it work only with absolute positioning and fixed height.

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/j6eWG/1/

Is there any way I can wrap my `.slider` around slides that will not have fixed height?
I need to make `.slider` the same height as `.slide.current` (http://jsfiddle.net/j6eWG/2/)

Maybe there is some transform property I can use?

Comment: Is the content of each slide ONLY text?  Are there images?

Comment: Yes, slides could also contain images or videos

Comment: Does the content mix?  Text + images OR Text + video?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by wrap the `.slider` around slides that will not have fixed height. Do you mean that the height needs to be dynamically adjusted based on each slide?

Comment: Sorry for my english, yes, some sort of it: I need to make `.slider` be the same height of the `.current` slide, Please see http://jsfiddle.net/j6eWG/2/